Unable to boot in operating system
I tried to install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on a Dell Inspiron N411Z, as the only OS, deleting the Windows 10 I had on it. The installation finished correctly, and it prompted me to restart the computer. When restarted, a message shows up saying "Operation System not found".
After through the Live USB I ran the Boot Repair in the Terminal.
I was given this link below:
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub2 of
sda1 into the MBR of sda.
Grub-efi will not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s



======================= Reinstall the grub2 of /dev/sda1 =======================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12-1ubuntu7

==> Reinstall the GRUB of /dev/sda1 into the MBR of /dev/sda

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-51-generic
Found memtest86+x64 image: /boot/memtest86+x64.bin
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.

The boot files of [sda1 (end>100GB)] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    biosdisk fshelp fat exfat ext2 ntfs ntfscomp part_msdos
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT16
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on sda1

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: A00(0.1) from Dell Inc.         
The firmware seems EFI-compatible, but this live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sda4    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda4    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 149.05 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Disk identifier: 90041FAB-0D02-4C5A-BECD-DC1D19B8C373
         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
sda1       4096 195393535 195389440 93.2G Linux filesystem
sda2       2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
sda3  195393536 206137343  10743808  5.1G Linux swap
sda4  206137344 207114239    976896  477M Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x43e21a5f
     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 61439935 61437888 29.3G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:160GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA TOSHIBA MK1655GS:;
2:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
1:2097kB:100GB:100GB:ext4::;
3:100GB:106GB:5501MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
4:106GB:106GB:500MB:fat16::;
sdb:31.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:VendorCo ProductCode:;
1:1049kB:31.5GB:31.5GB:fat32::boot, lba;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sda: 101130MiB:152628MiB:51498MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                   
├─sda1 ext4     631cd7d1-f3ab-433c-b9ed-e0383c503145 ce0380db-e640-47d3-a24b-12cf80bd95b8             
├─sda2                                               430c3d46-cc39-4f55-9d55-873b898f7eea             
├─sda3 swap     c5c85f77-bb1f-47d4-a89b-49abf32e4140 03816061-8ed9-4d0f-97d4-f98e1097508a             
└─sda4 vfat     E850-1747                            2c2ee8d9-4258-41d4-a15a-e885d3da7481             
sdb                                                                                                   
└─sdb1 vfat     DE6E-1C2E                            43e21a5f-01                          UBUNTU 24_0 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1               81.2G   6% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda4              476.7M   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
/dev/sdb1               23.5G  20% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1              ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda4              vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdb1              vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   631cd7d1-f3ab-433c-b9ed-e0383c503145
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda1/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/631cd7d1-f3ab-433c-b9ed-e0383c503145 / ext4 defaults 0 1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c5c85f77-bb1f-47d4-a89b-49abf32e4140 none swap sw 0 0

======================= sda1/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  54.141265869 = 58.133741568   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  54.135417938 = 58.127462400   boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
  81.234642029 = 87.225032704   boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  81.234642029 = 87.225032704   boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-51-generic                  1
  81.234642029 = 87.225032704   boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
   1.250682831 = 1.342910464    boot/initrd.img                                5
   1.250682831 = 1.342910464    boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-51-generic               5
   1.250682831 = 1.342910464    boot/initrd.img.old                            5

===================== sda1: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4  2024 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4  2024 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4  2024 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4  2024 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4  2024 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4  2024 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Apr  5  2024 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr  4  2024 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr  4  2024 41_custom

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

===================== sdb1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

for further troubleshooting in case the problem persist.
I still have the same problem Operating System not found.

Start a live session of Ubuntu.
Once the boot is complete, open a terminal and run:
 sudo apt install gparted
 sudo gparted

From gparted, select the hard drive.
Unmount it if it is mounted.
Create a new gpt partition table.
In the free space, create a 512-megabyte partition, Efy System partition (Fat32).
Next, create a 80-gigabyte partition, ext4 system.
Create another 16-gigabyte partition, swap system.
Create another remaining partition that you plan to use for Linux, ext4 system.
Apply the changes.
Close gparted.
Close the terminal
Start the installation
Choose manual partitioning and select:
Grub by default on the hard drive.
The 80-gigabyte partition for /
The 16-gigabyte partition for swap
The remaining for /home.
Continue with the installation.

Please help me with commands for each of the steps you have mentioned here @kyodake. Look at gparted below Partition
File System
Label
Size
Usad
Unused
Flags
/dev/sda2
grup2.core.img
1.00 MB
/dev/sda1
ext4
93.17 GİB
7:46 G18
65.71 GIB
/dev/sda3
linux-swap
5,12 GiB
9.06 MiB
511 GiB swap
/dev/sda4
fat16
477.00 MiB
/dev/sda5
ext4 boot
200.00 MiB
54.182 MiB
unallocated
unallocated
50.10 GIB
145.18 MiB
